# TypeScript Types Error when using functions with tap and map RxJS operators?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm getting strange TypeScript errors and I'm having difficulty deciphering what is wrong. My code runs fine but the PHPStorm IDE is throwing the following errors:

```
TS2345 Argument of Type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<{}>, Observable<{}>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Object, {}>'.
```

That error is on the tap function on the code below.

```
// Get Search Results
getSearchResults(payload: object): Observable<SearchResult[]> {
    let sbRef = this.snackBar.openFromComponent(SmallSpinnerComponent);
    let preparedPayload = this.addPayloadIdentifiers(payload);

    return this.http.post(environment.searchUrl, preparedPayload, {responseType: 'json'}).pipe(
        tap(res => console.log(res)),
        map(res => {
            sbRef.dismiss();
            return this.translateJSONResultSetV1(res);
        }),
        catchError(this.errorHandler.handleError(`getSearchResults error`))
);
}
```

If I comment the **tap** operator out completely, I get the following error on the **map** operator:

```
TS2345 Argument of Type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<{}>,
Observable<SearchResult[]>>' is not assignable to parameter of type
'OperatorFunction<Object, {}>'.
Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<{}>'
```

I'm tempted to think the error is really quite simple but I can't seem to figure out what is causing it. Additionally, the JSON payload being received from the RESTful requires quite a bit of processing on the client-side. This is unavoidable so I am using a helper function `translateJSONResultSetV1` in the **map** operator to return the right object types. Is this incorrect to use a function inside a **map** operator? Could this be causing the errors?

I want to stress that the code runs fine. However, if I'm working with the Observables incorrectly, I want to fix it so this code doesn't end up breaking with future updates.

***EDIT:*** RxJS Version 5.5.2

***Imports:***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from "../../../environments/environment";
import { catchError, map, tap} from "rxjs/operators";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import { ErrorHandlerService } from "./error-handler.service";
import { SearchFilterDropdown } from "../../classes/search-filter-dropdown";
import { SessionService } from "./session.service";
import { BusinessRule } from "../../classes/business-rule";
import { SearchResult } from "../../classes/search-result";
import { SectionHeading } from "../../classes/section-heading";
import { SmallSpinnerComponent } from "../../shared/small-spinner/small-spinner.component";
import { MatSnackBar } from "@angular/material";
```

Comment: What do your imports look like? And BTW, the sbRef.dismiss call in the map operator is semantically wrong. It's a side effect, so it should be inside a tap operator.

Comment: Also, what version of rxjs are you using?

Comment: Thanks for responding! I added the RxJS version (5.5.2) and imports. I actually initially had the `dismiss()` in the tap operator but moved it while trying to debug. I'll put it back there but that wouldn't fix the issue. I still get the same error.

Comment: I would try `tap<Object>(res => console.log(res))`.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: In all honesty, no. We upgraded to Angular 6 before deployment which meant some RxJS stuff needed to be reworked anyway. Since the code worked fine and there were no errors being thrown, we ran with it.

Comment: I'm currently getting the same with Angular 8 in 2020. As in your case, the code compiles and works fine, only vscode is showing it as an error.

Comment: After digging a little bit deeper I came across this answer which actually solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52141448/134120
Just deleting the node_modules folder should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

My money is on your use of the `catchError` operator. The statement `this.errorHandler.handleError('getSearchResults error')` will need to return a method that returns an observable.

`catchError` is like a switchMap when the source observable errors and could then infer a different type. This *edge case* operator has the ability to produce an error that "is really quite simple but I can't seem to figure out what is causing it."